# Run Ejb schduler each working day at 8pm

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Not sure how to configure *@javax.ejb.Schedule* annotation to be run at 8pm each working day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the `hour` attribute to set it for just 8pm and the `dayOfWeek` parameter to select the days. For example:

```
    @Schedule(hour="20",dayOfWeek="1,2,3,4,5")
```

Should run at 8pm Monday to Friday.